# run python script from index.js cloud function

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a python script from a node.js- cloud functions index file.
in order to access python script, I am also using "python-shell" ...
the problem is every time I run deploy my functions of the index.js file,
it prints this error:

```
Error: python: can't open file '../Python36/fListener.py': [Errno 2] 
                     No such file or directory

at PythonShell.parseError (/user_code/node_modules/python-
 shell/index.js:190:17)
at terminateIfNeeded (/user_code/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:78:9)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

also, I tried to create python project in the node.js 'functions' folder but it's pointing me on different 'import' errors on libraries which I am trying to use on python's script.something like this:

```
 File "py_project/fListener.py", line 1, in <module>
      import sseclient
```

what is the correct way to execute python script via node.js cloud functions??

thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your directory structure.

Comment: C:\Users\mkdan\nodejs\functions\py_env - this is where my 'Lib', 'Scripts' ..etc.    C:\Users\mkdan\nodejs\functions\social_py - is  where my python's script

Comment: the 'index.js' file is also in - C:\Users\mkdan\nodejs\functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit different approach for calling a Python script from a Cloud Function, without usage of python-shell. The idea is to package the Python code with [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) ("a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables") into a self-executable unit that is later used by a function executed by a node.js script. It was discussed more in depth in this [Stack Overflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092342/using-google-cloud-function-to-spawn-a-python-script).

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)